# MongoCollection.insertOne exception after upgrading springboot to 2.6.2

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Ive upgraded my app to spring boot 2.6.2, and I'm having difficulties with my mongodb..
my app is running, but when I try to activate one of my services, I get this exception of NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/mongodb/client/result/InsertOneResult;",

tried playing with my mongo versions, but nothing seems to work.
help will be appriciated
thank you

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/mongodb/client/result/InsertOneResult;",
        "errorReasonCodeDescription": "org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/mongodb/client/result/InsertOneResult;
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1082)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
     org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
     org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:68)2
     org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.instrument.web.TraceWebServletConfiguration$LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletConfiguration.java:129)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
     org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
     org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.tomcat.TraceValve.invoke(TraceValve.java:74)
     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
    t org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
     java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/mongodb/client/result/InsertOneResult;
```

this is my pom file

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<!-- Artifact Information -->
<groupId>com.aa</groupId>
<artifactId>payments</artifactId>
<version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <logstash.version>6.3</logstash.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2021.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>${logstash.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard
        </artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.30</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Thanks for using https://jar-download.com -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- End of saf services -->


</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dep</id>
        <properties>
            <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <directory>target-dep</directory>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>true</executable>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>repackage</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>exec</classifier>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>jar</id>
        <properties>
            <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>prepare-agent</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-unit-test</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                                <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <!-- Add the following exclusions here. -->
            <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>properties</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```